# SSL certificate for specific directories

Tags: ssl, directory

So I've got a login script (domain.com/script/index.php) that I need protected with a self-signed certificate, but installing a cert with Apache will apply it to my whole domain. My domain is a personal website, and the last thing I would want is for someone to go through the hassle of having to jump through the hoops of having to 'trust' my self-signed certificate.

Right now I have Webmin running on my server, and it currently has its own self-signed without applying it to my root website directory. Is there any way to secure my script directory without applying it to my root directory?

Comment: "Installing a cert with Apache will apply it to my whole domain" Of course, but not to every resource in that domain. You can specify which resources need SSL at the directory level already, via the [`SSLRequireSSL`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl) directive. Off topic.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the help. I've included SSLRequireSSL in my 000-default.conf but am now getting 403 forbidden through browser and: **access to /var/www/site.com/script/ failed, reason: SSL connection required** in error.log. Google doesn't return much on this.

Comment: @EJP In relation to my last question, the problem was that I wasn't accessing my site through https/443. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume this is php and apache:

Just add this lines to your vhost configs:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile {{SERVER CRT PATH}}
SSLCertificateKeyFile {{SERVER CRT PATH}}
```

Make sure SSL dll is on in the php.ini

and apply like so:

```
# Local Php site
<VirtualHost *:83>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot C:/xampp2/htdocs/scripts/php

  <Directory C:/xampp2/htdocs/scripts/php>
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted

  </Directory>

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile C:\xampp2\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\xampp2\apache\conf\ssl.key\server.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Reference: http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords

restart apache then visit: https://localhost:83